# Elmah with log4net doesn't log

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, log4net, elmah

I'm new in Elmah's world and I'm trying to see my log (in a web.api project) with it, but it doesn't work. I think I'm missing some configuration :(

Here is the configuration I have:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Web.config

```
<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  <sectionGroup name="elmah">
    <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web>    
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>    
  </httpModules>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  </httpHandlers>  
</system.web>

<elmah>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~\App_Data\" />
  <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
</elmah>

<log4net>
  <logger name="PROJECT">
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="elmahappender" />
  </logger>
  <!--ELMAH Appender--> 
  <appender name="elmahappender" type="elmahappender_log4net.ELMAHAppender, elmahappender_log4net">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <UseNullContext>False</UseNullContext>
  </appender>
</log4net>

<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />      
    <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />    
  </handlers>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
  </modules>    
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? 
Note: If I use another appender like (FileAppender), it works!
Thanks!

Comment: Your first step should be to enable log4net debug logging and look for any errors. This [blog post from 10 years ago](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/) will help.

Comment: Hello Stuartd, thanks for your answer but my problem it is not that. Log4net works fine when I use FileAppender as appender, but when I use ELMAH it doesn't work, so I think I'm missing some configuration. If you have any other idea it's welcome.

Comment: Log4net will use appenders that are correctly configured, and ignore those that aren't - but it will also output details of **what** configuration is invalid to debug logging.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem after read a lot of foros and posts. I created an ActionFilterAttribute and after that, all my exceptions are logged OK in ELMAH. Here is my code in case anyone will need it.

```
public class ElmahLogger : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
      {
         if ((actionExecutedContext.Response != null) && !actionExecutedContext.Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
            try
            {
                var messages = (System.Web.Http.HttpError)((System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<System.Web.Http.HttpError>)actionExecutedContext.Response.Content).Value;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var keyValuePair in messages)
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(keyValuePair.Value.ToString());

                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new HttpException((int)actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode, stringBuilder.ToString()));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Error in ElmahLoggerFilter - OnActionExecuted: " + ex.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

And of course, you need to register your filter in WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new ElmahLogger());
    }
}
```

Enjoy it! :)

Comment: You shouldn't write that code yourself. There's a [contrib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.Contrib.WebApi/) project for ELMAH to handle Web API. I wrote a post (http://docs.elmah.io/logging-to-elmah-io-from-web-api/) about how to install and configure it using [elmah.io](https://elmah.io/), but the procedure is the same with the XML logger. Just don't install the elmah.io package but elmah.corelibrary only and configure it using a one-liner :)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasArdal for your post!